# Access denied for outbound DCOM authentication, but not inbound

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016, powershell-5.1

I found an old reporting tool has been failing to run this powershell on ServerA, to query WMI from ServerB:

```bash
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName ServerB

Get-WmiObject : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

# WsMAN works from ServerA
Get-Service -ComputerName ServerB  ## success
Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName ServerB  ## success
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName ServerA  ## success (local)

# specifying credentials manually gives same error:
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName ServerB -Credential (Get-Credential)  ## Access is denied
# wmic as well
wmic /NODE:"ServerB" OS get name  ## access is denied
```

For some reason, ServerA cannot use DCOM authentication to connect out to remote machines. Other machines CAN connect to ServerA using DCOM through, which makes it weird.

Other troubleshooting:

- The user is an admin on both servers
- Also occurs for other users
- Other devices can connect to ServerB with no issues
- ServerB cannot connect to other devices

---

And I've found another (exchange) report is broken, as `Test-ServiceHealth` relies on WMI

Comment: they use different protocols, Cim uses WinRM and Wmi uses DCOM thats most likely the issue

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon you're right, `New-CimSession -ComputerName ServerB -SessionOption (New-CimSessionOption -Protocol Dcom)` does fail from ServerA, and succeeds from ServerB. Any idea what affects it, where it would choke outbound, but not in?

Comment: You would essentially need to do the opposite of this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-disable-dcom-support-in-windows-2bb8c280-9698-7f9c-bf67-2625a5873c7b#:~:text=Click%20the%20Default%20Properties%20tab,enable%20(or%20disable)%20DCOM. on `ServerB`

Comment: Probably better link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/setting-machine-wide-security-using-dcomcnfg

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon other machines can connect to ServerB using DCOM, so ServerB is good. ServerA cannot connect *out* via DCOM to any target, it's just weird. The access denied makes me think it's making invalid requests, but I'm not sure how I'd tell or fix that

Comment: Did you check for any outbound rule that would deny DCOM traffic on ServerA ? Other than that, not sure. I think the folks on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) might provide better troubleshooting of the issue

Comment: yep looks like it's able to connect in general, and I'd think it would throw a connection failure style of error instead. I may ask over there if I don't find anything

Comment: For admin to work both local and remote machine has to be in same group that shares a common Password Server.  Just because a user has Admin on both machines doesn't mean the admin is the same account.